# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fn')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

I don't understand why i keep getting this error. Please help.

```
*** --------------------------------------------
 * AdminLTE CardRefresh.js
 * License MIT
 * --------------------------------------------
 */

import $ from 'jquery'

/**
 * Constants
 * ====================================================
 */

const NAME = 'CardRefresh'
const DATA_KEY = 'lte.cardrefresh'
const EVENT_KEY = `.${DATA_KEY}`
const JQUERY_NO_CONFLICT = $.fn[NAME]

const EVENT_LOADED = `loaded${EVENT_KEY}`
const EVENT_OVERLAY_ADDED = `overlay.added${EVENT_KEY}`
const EVENT_OVERLAY_REMOVED = `overlay.removed${EVENT_KEY}`

const CLASS_NAME_CARD = 'card'

const SELECTOR_CARD = `.${CLASS_NAME_CARD}`
const SELECTOR_DATA_REFRESH = '[data-card-widget="card-refresh"]'
```

Comment: sounds like jquery is not loading

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

Looks like it's undefined. Try instead

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'
```

Answer (score 0):

Update 2023:

I used this code snippet to fix all the problems I had!

As of bootstrap 5 they will require you to use their [Proper](https://popper.js.org/) . And here I use [Bundle](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/) and it still works well with all functions

**for nextjs 13**

```
      <Script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js" />
      <Script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2" />
      <Script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
        crossOrigin="anonymous"
      />
```